# Highchart renders differently for height on first click

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I have created a highchart that is set inside a chart object in html, with css of height and width set to the chart object. On first render, the chart has an initial height of 290px. After I click on the tab again the chart is stretched and has a height of 308px. Every other click after that has no effect, also having height of 308px. here is my code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="content">
    <chart class="chartContainer" [options]="myChart" type="chart" 
     style="display: block;">
    </chart>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .chartContainer{
                      position: absolute;
                      height: 100%;
                      z-index: -1;
                      overflow-y: hidden;
                      background-color: rgba(244, 244, 244, 0.98);
                      padding-top: 25px;
                      padding-bottom: 30px;
                      margin: auto;
                    }
```

Typescript:

```
addChart(){

    this.myChart = {

      chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)',
        reflow: false
      },
      credits: {
        enabled: false
      },
      tooltip: { 
        enabled: false 
      },
      title: {
        text:""
      },
      responsive: false,
      xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 5
      },
      yAxis: {
        visible:false,
        resize: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },
      plotOptions: {
        series: {
            marker: {
              enabled: true,
              radius: 4,
              symbol: 'cicle'
            },
            lineWidth: 1,
               dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#8C88FF',
                 style: {
                    fontWeight: 'none',
                    textOutline: 'none',
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontFamily:'Trebuchet MS'
                }
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
      },
      series: [{
        showInLegend: false,  
        name: 'High',
        color: '#8C88FF',
        data: [[5, 120], [7, 140], [8, 135], [9, 120], [10, 120], 
              [12, 135], [15, 160],[20, 135],[21, 135], [22, 135]]
      }, 
      {
        showInLegend: false,  
        name: 'Low',
        color: '#8C88FF',
        data: [[5, 100], [7, 120], [8, 120], [9, 115], [10, 110], 
              [12, 125], [15, 140],[20, 130],[21, 125], [22, 125]]
      }]
    } 
    console.log("Chart created");
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the jsfiddle link ? The problem i think because parent div has class .content does not fixed width and height but the child div has attribute height : 100%

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue here: http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/t5n49n3x/ but everything seems to work fine. 

Highcharts reflows the chart when the size of the window changes: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.reflow
If the size of the container changes the chart will adjust to the maximum available space.

Comment: I found the fix, please see my answer and it'd be great if someone can explain why, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I directly declared my chart before ViewDidLoad it works. Otherwise if I declare it in addChart which is called in ViewDidload it renders differently for the first draw.